# Calling sql server stored procedure within vb.net webservice within for each loop

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services

I have a vb.net webservice that receive a list of complex objects, loops through the objects, attempts to connect to sql server to invoke a stored procedure and returns the id of the data was inserted.

this is my web service code

```
Public Class MediSenseLog
        Public ID As Integer
        Public LogDate As String

    End Class

<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Sample( ByVal logs As MediSenseLog()) As String
        LSSID = "22"
        Dim numLogs As Integer = logs.Length ' number of logs received 
        Dim LogsSent(2, numLogs) As String ' set up a multidimensional array

        Dim cmd1 As New OdbcCommand

        Dim LSID As Int64
        Dim str As String = "" 'holds a built up string so that I can see what it is returning

        For i = 0 To numLogs - 1
            Dim log As MediSenseLog = logs(i)
            Try
                Using sqlconnect1 As New OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BasicConnectionString").ConnectionString)
                    sqlconnect1.Open()
                    cmd1.Connection = sqlconnect1
                    cmd1.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd1.CommandText = "{ CALL spInsertLogsSubmitted(?,?,?,?) }"

                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LSSID", Int64.Parse(LSSID))
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileAppLogID", Int64.Parse(log.ID.ToString))
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileAppLogDate", DateTime.Parse(log.LogDate.ToString))

                    Dim id As OdbcParameter
                    id = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@LSID", OdbcType.BigInt)
                    id.Direction = Data.ParameterDirection.Output

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    str = str & "*" & log.ID.ToString & "*" & log.LogDate.ToString & "*" & id.Value.ToString
                    LSID = Int64.Parse(id.Value) ' return value from stored pprocedure

                    LogsSent(0, i) = log.ID.ToString
                    LogsSent(1, i) = log.LogDate.ToString
                    LogsSent(2, i) = id.Value.ToString

                End Using
            Catch e As OdbcException

            End Try
        Next i

        Return str
    End Function
```

This is my stored procedure

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertLogsSubmitted](
    @LSSID bigint,
    @MobileAppLogID bigint,
    @MobileAppLogDate datetime,
    @LSID bigint output
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON


    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO [tblLogsSubmitted]([LSSID],[MobileAppLogID],[MobileAppLogDate])
        VALUES( @LSSID,@MobileAppLogID,@MobileAppLogDate)

        set @LSID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

END
```

The problem i'm having is that something goes wrong within the for loop and the second time the loop executed it seems to cache the first values and output parameter returns dbnull. 
If i take out the for loop and manually call the code above by replacing i with 0 then 1.... ( Dim log As MediSenseLog = logs(0)) the code works perfectly.

What am i doing wrong within this for loop?

Comment: "The problem i'm having is that something goes wrong within the for loop" - have you considered using the debugger?

Comment: I dont know how to debug a webservice. Its an android app that calls the webservice. so what i do is i just keep returning values to try and see where the problem is hence the str string. The second time in the for loop it inserts the values for the 1st object and then the output from stored procedure is null. Thats as far as i gather. Can you assist me in debugging another way?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to call `cmd1.Parameters.Clear()` before adding the parameters. Also, if you're using SQL Server it would be better to use SqlClient instead of OdbcClient (you get to name the parameters and it'll be optimised for SQL Server). And, if you can, avoid `.AddWithValue` and use the `.Add` method instead as it prevents it from having to guess the data type - it *might* get it right, or it might not. Finally, you have an empty `Catch` which will be hiding errors from you: you need to see those errors.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew Morton. I did exactly as you said and it works perfectly.

Comment: I've made the first part of my comment into an answer so that you can accept it if you want to, and it'll make it easier for anyone else finding your question to see what solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time through the loop, you are adding to the command's ParameterCollection. This means that only the first ones get read... again and again. You need to clear the collection before adding the new ones with `cmd1.Parameters.Clear()`.